# Cannot mount external FreeNAS NFS on XenServer VM or Dom0

Tags: nfs, mount, xenserver, truenas

I'm hoping someone can help identify a problem or at least send me in the right direction.

I've created an NFS share on FreeNAS. The server has an external IP. I can mount this on my Debian machine (which is on the local network) with:

```
mount -t nfs 1.2.3.4:/mnt/backup /mnt/backup
```

I can't mount this from any VM on my XenServer machine or on Dom0. I've exhausted my Google searching abilities. The following is the command I am running and the verbose return. I appreciate any help! Thank you

```
mount -v -t nfs -o tcp 1.1.1.1:/mnt/backup /mnt/backup

mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Apr 12 16:51:43 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'tcp,vers=4,addr=1.1.1.1,clientaddr=2.2.2.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'tcp,addr=1.1.1.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 1.1.1.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 1.1.1.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 790
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'tcp,vers=4,addr=1.1.1.1,clientaddr=2.2.2.2
```

Comment: What if you remove `-o tcp` from your `mount` command ? Also, is your FreeNAS server ip 1.1.1.1 or 1.2.3.4 ?

Comment: FreeNAS IP is 1.1.1.1 (well, not really obviously!). I'd read that XenServer requires TCP NFS connection but removing -o tcp gives:

mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Apr 12 17:49:39 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=1.1.1.1,clientaddr=2.2.2.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out

Comment: Are you able to ping your FreeNAS IP from your XenServer machine ?

Comment: Yes I can ping the server. RPCINFO gives this though: rpcinfo -t 1.1.1.1 nfs
rpcinfo: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
program 100003 is not available

Comment: I don't use FreeNAS, so i talk blindly. From the doc `rpcbind` uses TCP/UDP 111 and `nfsd` uses TCP 2049. Are you able to `telnet 1.1.1.1 111` and `telnet 1.1.1.1 2049` ? If not, also check this from your working Debian machine and compare. You could also compare a `tcpdump` trace from the working and from the non-working machine (I am thinking about filters on the way (iptables/Firewall)

Comment: Thanks for your help Kris, I can't telnet the ports even with iptables disabled. I am out of ideas!

Comment: Even from the the working Debian machine ?

Comment: IIRC, nfs has its own (simplistic) IP filter, so only allowed servers can connect to an exported share. Have you ensured that the IP of your VM is allowed access to the exported nfs share?